# Hard drive sometimes not detected?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I have an internal hard drive (E:/) that is not showing up sometimes. If I reboot my computer it will sometimes appear, and sometimes not. It is a 335gb 7200 rpm IDE.

All of my data seems to be intact, and I have checked the cables to make sure no disconnections have occurred.

Anyone have a suggestion for where to start diagnosis?

Comment: Ok this is weird. I just restarted my computer, and saw the drive in my computer. I then clicked on a shortcut on my desktop (which points to a folder on the problem drive). After clicking the shortcut, I got the spinning circle. When I open up my computer now, the drive is there but the blue bar showing available space is not shown (like it was shortly after startup). Trying to open the drive gives me a blue spinning circle (like the drive can't be found).

Comment: After waiting a little while I now get the message: E:\work refers to a location that is unavailable. It could be on a hard drive on this computer, or on a network. Check to make sure that the disk is properly inserted, or that you are...

Comment: And it is no longer being shown in the my computer area.

Comment: I just restarted again and now I can access that folder by clicking on the desktop shortcut... so weird

Comment: I just opened the drive and clicked on a different folder, and it froze again. (After successfully opening other folders several times.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest starting your diagnosis process by backing the drive up ;).

Then, if its a seagate drive, run [seatools](http://www.seagate.com/www/en-us/support/downloads/seatools) or its counterpart for the drive make - ifI tend to favour running [smartmontools](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/smartmontools/wiki) with its [gui](http://gsmartcontrol.berlios.de/home/index.php/en/Home) instead and run the smart tests in order (from short to long)- you can find a comprehensive list of attributes on this [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.)

Chances are if the drive is blinking out, chances of failure are fairly high,

Comment: +1: 335GB IDE sounds kind of old.  SMART tools is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using something like HDTune - you can check the SMART statistics and run a surface scan.

Regardless, until you have firm indications that your disk is still OK, I'd think about archiving it off elsewhere, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have 2 internal hard drives? 
If not then it might be a case of your partition table being corrupt.

Comment: I have 3, two Sata and one IDE. The IDE is the one acting up.

Comment: I hope you have gone through the normal checks of checking the cables connected and even checking if the hard disk is working (if possible try and hear the humming sound). Try using the diagnostic tools that came with the system, chances are your hard disk is on the verge of crashing

Comment: I faced the same issue sometime back and in the end it turned out to be a bad crashed hard disk.